# My jQuery POST is not adding the body to the request?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to send a `POST` with jQuery.  Here is my code:

```
        var s = {
            "first_name": "Jimi",
            "last_name": "Hendrix",
            "rank": "Boy Scout",
            "email": "jimi@gmail.com"
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:9000/scouts',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {scout: s},
            beforeSend: function (request) {
                request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            }
        });
```

But the `data` is not added to the request.  My network tab shows that my headers are provisional and the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is not set either.  Here is my network tab:
[image]
Why is my body not being attached?  What do I need to do to set the headers?

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is not a _request_ header, it is a _response_ header the server has to send to inform client whether or not they should permit requests across domain boundaries …

Answer (score 0):

You ajax request has been blocked (there is an error in your console).

Access-Control-Allow-Origin must be set by localhost:9000 not from localhost:8080.

Comment: I don't have an error in my console.  My `express` server is using the `cors` plugin and should have the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` set to `*`.